# Download multiple files: best performance-wise solution

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I am writing an application which needs to read thousands (let's say 10000) of small (let's say 4KB) files from a remote location (e.g., an S3 bucket).

The single read from remote takes around 0.1 seconds and processing the file takes just few milliseconds (from 10 to 30). Which is the best solution in terms of performance?

- The worse I can do is to download everything serially: 0.1*10000 = 1000 seconds (~16 minutes).
- Compressing the files in a single big one would surely help, but it is not an option in my application.
- I tried to spawn N threads (where N is the number of logical cores) that download and process 10000/N files each. This gave me 10000/N * 0.1 seconds. If N = 16, it takes indeed around 1 minute to complete
- I also tried to spawn K*N threads (this helps sometimes on high latency systems, as GPUs) but I did not get much speed up for any value of K (I tried 2,3,4), maybe due to lot of context thread switching.

My general question is: how would you design such a similar system? Is 1 minute really the best I can achieve?

Thank you,
Giuseppe

Comment: Try multiple threads for downloading the file and single thread for writing into the FS. The downloading threads would just put the content to the queue from which the writer thread would be reading. Avoid copying of the read contents from the network. You could also try things like `aio`, but I dont think that would be needed

Comment: Does it make sense to launch more threads than cores?

Comment: Yes, it does in your case. Anyways, nobody can't be sure unless you profile it. But, I would start with threads equal to number of cores first and then increase it and see if it helps or not.

Comment: As with any performance optimization, you should always first profile your code and see what's crippling your performance. Without that, we can only guess. For example, it takes 100ms do download 4kb file and you see a linear increase with number of parallel requests, which hints (but not proves) you're establishing a separate connection for each file. So, are you making use of Keep-Alive/Persistent Connection? With it, you should see a HUGE performance boost even with serial download.

Comment: I am. I have a pool of C connections each one dying after x seconds (C and x can be tuned) otherwise get reused for transferring other files. Among other things, I don't  get why launching 10000 threads (with C = 10000 and x big)  do not make things faster. It's true that my parallelism is only 16, but I thought I could still download the files altogether. What am I missing?